# How to configure build dependencies for HMS Location services?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

How do I use the location service on the HMS mobile phone?Specifically, which dependencies should be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the following dependencies to use location services:

```
dependencies {       
  implementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:{version}'     
}
```

Note:
Replace {version} with the actual SDK version number, for example: implementation'com.huawei.hms:location:4.0.2.300'. If you also integrate other HMS services, it is recommended that you use the same version of the HMS SDK.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add necessary Maven repository in project level build gradle file. After that you should add location dependencies in app level build.gradle file.

Project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/' } // HUAWEI Maven repository
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.3.1.300'
    }
}

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

App level build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:4.0.3.301'
}
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
```

Comment: I recommend putting Huawei's repo the last, otherwise each time Gradle has to search for dependencies it will search on Huawei's repo before JCenter, impacting your build times.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put Huawei's maven repository at the end line and use https,such as

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' } 

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.3.1.300'
    }
}

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }

    }
}
```

the doc in the huawei website:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/location-preparation#h2-1580888386039-0